# Two main java classes maven. Run each one individually through terminal

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with two main classes and would like to run each class individually from the command like so:

```
java -jar appName.jar -cp com.green.RunApp1
java -jar appName.jar -cp com.blue.RunApp2
```

I tried adding the absolute paths to both classes in execute tags but doing so did not allow me to run them individually. 

For instance, RunApp1 would always run no matter which main class I pointed to when running the jar. I am pretty sure its something minor that I am overlooking.

My pom.xml:

```
 <build>
   <resources>
      <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
         <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
   </resources>
   <testResources>
      <testResource>
         <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
         <filtering>false</filtering>
      </testResource>
   </testResources>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.7</version>
         <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>default-resources</id>
               <phase>process-resources</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>resources</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
               <id>default-testResources</id>
               <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>testResources</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.5.1</version>
         <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>default-testCompile</id>
               <phase>test-compile</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>testCompile</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
               <id>default-compile</id>
               <phase>compile</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration />
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.8.1</version>
         <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>default-deploy</id>
               <phase>deploy</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>deploy</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.3</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>default-deploy</id>
               <phase>deploy</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>deploy</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
         <configuration>
            <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why do you want to run them during the build? Which phases do you want to bind them to?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your main classes with different IDs in the  section. Something like this:

```
<execution>
    <id>main1</id>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>Main1</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
    <id>main2</id>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>Main2</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Answer (score 1):

i was able to get it to work by making two different profiles but i have to build two different jars for it work which defeats the purpose. heres my new pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Tiger</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-resources</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-testResources</id>
                            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testResources</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-testCompile</id>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-compile</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.abc.Tiger</mainClass>
                        <jvmArguments>
                                -Dtest.dbUser=${test.dbUser}
                                -Dtest.dbPassword=${test.dbPassword}
                                -Dtest.environment=${test.environment}
                            </jvmArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>nexus</serverId>
                        <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>Lion</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-resources</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-testResources</id>
                            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testResources</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-testCompile</id>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-compile</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.abc.Lion</mainClass>
                        <jvmArguments>
                                -Dtest.dbUser=${test.dbUser}
                                -Dtest.dbPassword=${test.dbPassword}
                                -Dtest.environment=${test.environment}
                            </jvmArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>nexus</serverId>
                        <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

heres how i build them and run them.

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests  -P Tiger
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=Tiger target/amazingApp.jar
mvn clean package -DskipTests  -P Lion
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=Lion target/amazingApp.jar
```

this is not what i was expecting. instead, i would like to build one jar and switch between profiles within the single jar. could someone point me in the right direction?